# Find out if there is any non-NA value for each id

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping

In the following data frame in long format (i.e., one row per measurement point), I would like to find out which person (variable *ID*) has only NA's on both *Var1* and *Var2* and which person has at least one non-NA value on either *Var1* or *Var2*. Those with only NA values should be in Group 0 and those that have at least one non-NA value should be in Group 1.

```
df <- read.table(text=
"ID       Var1   Var2      
800057    NA    NA               
800057    NA    NA           
800057    NA    NA          
800057    NA    1         
800057    NA    NA 
800119    NA    NA 
800119    NA    NA          
800119    NA    NA      
834011     1    NA
834011     3    NA  
834341    NA    NA
834341    5     NA  
834341    NA    NA   
834341    NA    NA   
834341    3     NA", header=TRUE)
```

My result would then look like this:

```
df <- read.table(text=
"ID       Var1  Var2  Group    
800057    NA    NA   1            
800057    NA    NA   1        
800057    NA    NA   1       
800057    NA    1    1     
800057    NA    NA   1
800119    NA    NA   0
800119    NA    NA   0       
800119    NA    NA   0   
834011     1    NA   1
834011     3    NA   1
834341    NA    NA   1
834341    5     NA   1   
834341    NA    NA   1
834341    NA    2    1
834341    3     NA   1", header=TRUE)
```

I want to try out a solution using `group_by(ID)` and `mutate()` to create the Group variable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use  `all` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Group = as.integer(!all(is.na(Var1) & is.na(Var2))))

#       ID  Var1  Var2 Group
#    <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 800057    NA    NA     1
# 2 800057    NA    NA     1
# 3 800057    NA    NA     1
# 4 800057    NA     1     1
# 5 800057    NA    NA     1
# 6 800119    NA    NA     0
# 7 800119    NA    NA     0
# 8 800119    NA    NA     0
# 9 834011     1    NA     1
#10 834011     3    NA     1
#11 834341    NA    NA     1
#12 834341     5    NA     1
#13 834341    NA    NA     1
#14 834341    NA    NA     1
#15 834341     3    NA     1
```

Or can change the last line to use `any` :

```
mutate(Group = as.integer(any(!is.na(Var1) | !is.na(Var2))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` solution would be comparing the count of `NA` rows, `is.na()`, to the count of entries in each group, `n()`. Since we have two variables, `n()` needs to be multiplied by two. Plus sign `+` before the comparison converts the boolean to numeric.

```
library(dplyr)
```

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(group = +(sum(is.na(Var1), is.na(Var2)) < 2 * n()))
```

Last line can be replaced with the following to avoid doing any comparisons.

```
  mutate(group = +(as.logical(sum(is.na(Var1), is.na(Var2)) - 2 * n())))
```

---

---

```
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [4]
#>        ID  Var1  Var2 group
#>     <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1 800057    NA    NA     1
#>  2 800057    NA    NA     1
#>  3 800057    NA    NA     1
#>  4 800057    NA     1     1
#>  5 800057    NA    NA     1
#>  6 800119    NA    NA     0
#>  7 800119    NA    NA     0
#>  8 800119    NA    NA     0
#>  9 834011     1    NA     1
#> 10 834011     3    NA     1
#> 11 834341    NA    NA     1
#> 12 834341     5    NA     1
#> 13 834341    NA    NA     1
#> 14 834341    NA    NA     1
#> 15 834341     3    NA     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `ifelse()` function in `base`.

```
df$group <- ifelse(is.na(df$Var1) & is.na(df$Var2), 1, 2) 

       ID Var1 Var2 group
1  800057   NA   NA     1
2  800057   NA   NA     1
3  800057   NA   NA     1
4  800057   NA    1     2
5  800057   NA   NA     1
6  800119   NA   NA     1
7  800119   NA   NA     1
8  800119   NA   NA     1
9  834011    1   NA     2
10 834011    3   NA     2
11 834341   NA   NA     1
12 834341    5   NA     2
13 834341   NA   NA     1
14 834341   NA   NA     1
15 834341    3   NA     2
```

#### Data:

```
df <- read.table(text=
"ID       Var1   Var2      
800057    NA    NA               
800057    NA    NA           
800057    NA    NA          
800057    NA    1         
800057    NA    NA 
800119    NA    NA 
800119    NA    NA          
800119    NA    NA      
834011     1    NA
834011     3    NA  
834341    NA    NA
834341    5     NA  
834341    NA    NA   
834341    NA    NA   
834341    3     NA", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Did you compare your output with OP's expected output?

Comment: I do not know what you refer as "OP", so I probably did not compare to it.

Comment: In the question there is expected output shown. I mean to compare it with that to verify if the answer that you get is correct.

Comment: Uhmm I see, yeah I did not compare